# Recommended High Availablity Architecture

Tags: deployment, aws

We are looking to use Craft CMS for an upcoming web project, are there any documented architectures or topologies for deploying into a production setup. This would be for high availablity across multiple regions including both front end assets and databases.

We are likely to consider AWS or Azure for hosting. If there is nothing specific about Craft architectures then would a standard PHP site topology be appropriate?

Thanks

Luke

Comment: Yes, that would be interesting... also for Element API ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing particularly necessary for Craft here, other than what would be needed for a standard PHP application.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/php-ha-tutorial.html

And some potentially useful Craft related information around this topic here:

[Load balancing nodes configuration (3 Craft nodes behind F5 Big-IP)](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4719/load-balancing-nodes-configuration-3-craft-nodes-behind-f5-big-ip)

[Craft admin login infinite redirect in cluster](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/12276/craft-admin-login-infinite-redirect-in-cluster)